# Jordan canonical form of a matrix $A$ with the property that $A^2 = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ has the property that $A^2 = 0$.  What are the possible Jordan canonical forms of such a matrix?

A matrix of the form:

\begin{pmatrix}
  a & a \\
  -a & -a  \\
 \end{pmatrix}

for $a \in \mathbb{C}$ will satisfy the $A^2 = 0$ property.  The characteristic polynomial of this matrix will be $(t-a)(t+a) + a^2 = t^2$  So the eigenvalues will be $0$.  Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Any Jordan blocks can be of most size 2. Because if they were bigger then at least one 1 would be left from the off diagonal of 1s after applying your power. The same argument can be used for $A^k = 0$ with Jordan blocks size $\leq k$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A^2=0$, so $A$ is nilpotent, so its only possible eigenvalue is $0$. So there are only $2$ possible Jordan canonical form :
$$\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}\text{ and }\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

In dimension $2$ one has the simplest case for the matrix in Jordan form will be (assuming it is not the zero matrix)

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1\\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$